# I want my actions to not use any type of account linking

Tags: actions-on-google

I want to publish this action but everytime I submit for production it shows the same message for denial. I don't want account linking of any type for my actions. Please help me in this problem.

[image: Denial reason]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems by mistake you have enabled Account Linking in your action.

**If you don't want** any kind of authentication or linking in your actions, check **Account Linking** section under **Develop** menu and clear it.

[image]

If it is linked you will get an option to clear it at the right side of the panel.

[image]

**If you want Account Linking** than you need to provide atleast one login credentials in testing credentials section.

[image]